# Using Azure active directory with Android

Tags: android, azure, xamarin.android, azure-active-directory

Iam creating an daily status updater app for a organization. I need to use the Azure active directory and Xamarin.Android  for the whole process. I also need to include authentication for the same. I just wanted to know where do I start from as I am very new to developing in Xamarin.

Any links or tutorials will be useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Azure AD C#/Xamarin sample for Android here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn646737.aspx#BKMK_Native

Hope this helps.